# why the mysqld is located in 4 places in linux system?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have confusion while I'm execute the command "# find / -name mysqld". Because the mysqld is located in four places which are:

1. /usr/libexec/mysqld
2. /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld
3. /var/lock/subsys/mysqld
4. /var/run/mysqld

What is the purpose of another three mysql daemons?

Comment: there is only one executable listed in the question above, not three.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the following explanations

- /usr/libexec/mysqld : The actual binary executable
- /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld : The service startup file (text file)
- /var/run/mysqld : PID/run file folder (mysqld writes a run file in this folder)
- /var/lock/subsys/mysqld : not sure

If you run `which mysqld` you should see the first one

You never run that directly

When you run `service mysqld start`, it calls `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld` to kickoff a program called `mysqld_safe` (Run `which mysqld_safe`). `mysqld_safe` and `mysqld` work together to be the server daemon.

In turn, `mysqld_safe` will kickoff mysqld and then checks for an exit code. You can run `less /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld` and see this. If mysqld did not end due to system shutdown or a normal `service mysql stop`, mysqld_safe will attempt to restart `mysqld`.

Comment: Thank u @RolandoMySQLDBA! what is the purpose of another three files except the service startup

Comment: The files/folder work together. `mysqld` make create files for the purpose of declaring itself as a service in certain folders.

Comment: I can't edit you answer thus I will add extra info as a comment:
/var/lock/subsys/mysqld is used by the OS to make sure that MySQL service is stopped correctly before shutting it down