# bash: /usr/sbin/mysqld: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, centos6, database-restore

I'm using  [this tutorial](http://egil.biz/how-to-recover-mysql-data-from-innodb/)  on How to recover MySQL data from Innodb which provides the following steps:

1. Restore data (`ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1` files) into the normal MySQL data directory ( /var/lib/mysql )
2. Move to data directory `/var/lib/mysql`
3. Run the command `ls -l` to find the size of your Innodb logfiles
4. The output looks like this:

   `-rw-rw—- 1 mysql mysql 5242880 Jun 25 11:30 ib_logfile0
   -rw-rw—- 1 mysql mysql 5242880 Jun 25 11:30 ib_logfile1`
5. Run `su mysql`
6. And run this `/usr/sbin/mysqld –innodb_log_file_size=5242880 –innodb_force_recovery=6` Note the number 5242880 is what I've got on step 4

Now I'm getting this error `bash: /usr/sbin/mysqld: No such file or directory` . 
What do I miss or what should I install ?

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Mysql is 5.5.4

Comment: He may not have been using centos6...I always start mysql on centos as `sudo etc/init.d/mysqld start` for mysql v5.5...I would just make the changes/add parameters to my.cnf and do a regular start and read log files to see if you get errors...

Comment: Do you really have mysql on the machine you are restoring with? It sort of sounds like you do since you have /var/lib/mysql sitting around. Does /usr/libexec/mysqld exist?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445357/why-the-mysqld-is-located-in-4-places-in-linux-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem by uninstalling and install again mysqlServer and taking the entire mysql directory `/var/lib/mysql` content from my backup to the new directory . I have all tables and data .